# perform edge detection on roi

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, roi

eight.jpg 
I use the eight image from matlab [eight.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZZH2.jpg)

and i have the following code:

```
FullImage = imread('eight.tif');
roi_col = [50 50 250 250];
roi_row = [200 50 50 200];
ROI_help1 = roipoly(FullImage,roi_col,roi_row);
roi_col = [100 70 200 200];
roi_row = [180 100 70 180];
ROI_help2 = roipoly(FullImage,roi_col,roi_row);
ROI=logical(ROI_help2-ROI_help1);
YourFilter = @(x) edge(FullImage,'Canny',0.1);
J = roifilt2(FullImage,ROI,YourFilter);
figure, imshow(FullImage)
overlay=imoverlay(FullImage,J,'red');
hold on;
imshow(overlay);
```

This gives me this: 
[edge detection performed with canny on roi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEHRk.jpg)

How can i perform canny edge detection only on the circle leaving the inner and outer red area untouched, so it should display the normal image there?

Comment: you mean `@(x) edge(x,'Canny',0.1);`?

Comment: No, that still gives me One's in J in the outer and inner area. There should be Zeros in J, where ROI has Zeros...

Comment: I mean, clearly that line is wrong. Not saying it will fix it, but you may want to have a re-read of your code and fix the most simple msitakes

Comment: ah ok. thanks for advise. i'm new to matlab. could you give me a hint? That would be helpful :)

Comment: Why is that line wrong? and whats the correct syntax?

Comment: I told you the correct syntax :/ . You are defining a function with an input `x`, you may as well use it no? that is the purpose of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.
just need to create a complement of ROI and substract from J

```
ROI_neg=imcomplement(ROI);
LOL=J-ROI_neg;
figure;
overlay=imoverlay(Image,LOL,'red');
hold on;
imshow(overlay);
```

However, if i use a different image (stitched images. too large to update) it wont work. Am i missing any specific requirements? Datatype etc? i use .tif